# Interpolation for maximum likelihood estimate of unigram and bigram

Tags: natural-language-processing

We are given the following corpus, modified from the one in the chapter:

```
<s> I am Sam </s>
<s> Sam I am </s>
<s> I am Sam </s>
<s> I do not like green eggs and Sam </s>
```

If we use linear interpolation smoothing between a maximum-likelihood bigram model and a Maximum-
Likelihood Estimate unigram model with λ1 = 1/2 and λ2 =1/2, what is P(Sam | am)? Include `<s>` and
`</s>`\verb in your counts just like any other token.

Comment: @D.W.♦ Please can you help?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  We discourage exercise-like questions that are just the statement of a task.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Please credit the original source of this exercise.